# Passing console output to Shiny reactively as a status update

Tags: r, console, shiny

I have created an application using R and Shiny and want to output everything that happens in the console to a special status window in the Shiny app.
Here is how the skeleton of the function called by Shiny application looks.

```
myfunction = function(x,y,path....){
if(...){...}
cat("Reading Database\n")
df = read.csv(...)
cat("Processing\n")
#MORE CODE
}
```

I want a status bar that shows the progress of the called function by viewing the `cat(...)` console outputs.
If yes, can it be done without making any changes to the original function (making changes only in server.R and/or ui.R)?

Comment: Does it have to be `cat` and not `message`? If you can use `message` then I have a solution. If it uses `cat` then I only know how to make all the output appear at once when the function finishes

Comment: Actually I didn't know about `message` function. I would appreciate to see your solution with `message`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with the normal Shiny approach of using reactivity. I tried getting it to work with `textOuput`+`printText` but I was unable. I'd love to see other solutions, but here is my solution that uses [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package to update the element instead of using reactivity. I hope this works for you, it's pretty simple.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

calculate <- function() {
  lapply(1:5, function(x) {
    message(x)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  })
  message("Done")
}

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), br(),
    actionButton("btn","Click me"), br(), br(),
    "Progress:",
    tags$pre(id = "progress")
  ),
  server = function(input,output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      withCallingHandlers({
        shinyjs::text("progress", "")
        calculate()
      },
      message = function(m) {
        shinyjs::text(id = "progress", text = m$message, add = TRUE)
      })
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Hi Dean, I am using my `function()` to extract data and it is used inside an `eventReactive` function to make the dataset reactive with button click. How can I use your code structure in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across [this answer](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/3830244757f8ca25d4b00ce389ea41b3) that may be what you are looking for.

The `withConsoleRedirect()` function sends the console output to the browser.